# Could not cast value of type __NSCFString

Tags: swift, swift3, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying out FCM messaging service. I have setup everything perfecting. When I receive message from FCM I get the following error. I am not sure what is wrong here:

```
AnyHashable("google.c.a.c_id"): 1586592282379086000, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:1515418580276498%f4373656f4373656]

Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1b4c70040) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1b4c70b80).

2018-01-08 19:06:21.198548+0530 Ozone[1067:540436] Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1b4c70040) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1b4c70b80).
```

The strange part is I created a seperate Push Notification App and put the same code, it is working there. What could be wrong here?

Here is the piece code: I am getting the error in let d : [String : Any].....line

```
UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {  
           print("Handle push from foreground\(notification.request.content.userInfo)")  

            let dict = notification.request.content.userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary  
            let d : [String : Any] = dict["alert"] as! [String : Any]  
            let body : String = d["body"] as! String  
            let title : String = d["title"] as! String  
            print("Title:\(title) + body:\(body)")  
            self.showAlertAppDelegate(title: title,message:body,buttonTitle:"ok",window:self.window!)  

}
```

Can some one help me with this? I know it is very general error but not sure why this is coming as it is working fine in another app.

Thanks!

Comment: `dict["alert"]` is `String` here, not `[String: Any]`. Check [`APS dictionary keys's types`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html). Also, **don't use** force casting everywhere.

Comment: @user28434 So what should I use?

Comment: If I change it string I get: Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: Well, that's because you can subscript `String` with `String`. And you should look @Bilal's answer for branching casts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alert` key can be string or dictionary (depends on your server). You can try this.

```
if let dict = notification.request.content.userInfo["aps"] as? [String : Any] {

    if let d = dict["alert"] as? [String : Any],
        let body = d["body"] as? String,
        let title = d["title"] as? String {

            print("Title:\(title) + body:\(body)")
    } else if let body = dict["alert"] as? String {

        print("body:\(body)")
    }
}
```

And also you should avoid force casting and don't use `NSDictionary` in swift.

Comment: This was an issue. I am surprised the same code worked fine in a different project.

Comment: is it possible to add more parameters in aps?